# Sorting in php Arrayss

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My sql table consists of ID,Book name,Genre and ratings.Currently my array from my sql table looks like this (output)

```
Array ( 
   [book] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array
              ( [0] => 1 
                [1] => book one 
                [2] => Fantasy/Horror 
                [4] => 8.9 )
        [1] => Array ( 
                [0] => 2 
                [1] => book two 
                [2] => Comedy 
                [4] => 8.3 ) ) )
```

i want to sort this array to DESC by ID 
Also in the future by title.
The array variable is `$book` so i wrote `ksort($book)` also tried `arsort`
for some reason it doesnt work? Is it because of the array? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you specify the order clause of your SQL query? That will be quicker than sorting in PHP. It will also allow for ordering by multiple columns

Comment: oh i didnt think of that! i will try it now! but will it still work even thought it an array>

Comment: @shell It will appear in your array how it gets output from your query.

Comment: Otherwise [usort](http://php.net/usort) is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IF you are able to:**
Use SQL sorting instead, because of the speed and flexibility (Use db-engine where it's appropiate) Only use array-functionality if you really need to! :-)
Do something like:

```
SELECT ID,Book name,Genre, ratings ORDER BY ID DESC
```

**OR**

***If you have still have to use array sorting***, use usort() in PHP:

```
<?php
//Book array
$bookArray['book'][0] = array(2, 'book one', 'Fantasy/Horror', 8.9);
$bookArray['book'][1] = array(1, 'book two ', 'Comedy', 8.3);

function sortByIndex($a, $b) {
    return $a[0] - $b[0];
}

usort($bookArray['book'], 'sortByIndex');


echo 'RESULT=' . print_r($bookArray,true);

?>
```

Results in this output:
RESULT=Array ( [book] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => book two [2] => Comedy [3] => 8.3 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => book one [2] => Fantasy/Horror [3] => 8.9 ) ) )

Book two comes first here, because in my example I set the first index to be 1 with value 'book two'.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add this to your SQL statement at the end:

```
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Also if you really want to know how to do it in PHP you would do it this way:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a[0] == $b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[0] > $b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array['book'], "cmp");
```

Comment: You don't need to use the function I wrote when you do the ORDER BY in your sql query

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to change your Select Statement. It should be something like this -

```
select id,bookname,genre,ratings from yourtable ORDER BY id DESC,bookname;
```